# Merging date ranges in R

Tags: r

I have this dataframe (called `signal`):

```
         Date Sig
1  2012-03-25  Go
2  2012-04-15 Stop
3  2012-04-22 Stop
4  2012-05-13 Stop
5  2012-05-20 Stop
6  2012-06-24  Go
7  2012-09-23  Go
8  2012-09-30  Go
9  2012-10-14 Stop
10 2012-12-02  Go
11 2012-12-16 Stop
```

And I am trying to merge/join the date ranges in order to create something like that:

```
        Start        Stop Sig
1  2012-03-25  2012-04-15 Go
2  2012-04-15  2012-06-24 Stop
3  2012-06-24  2012-10-14 Go
4  2012-10-14  2012-12-02 Stop
5  2012-12-12  2012-12-16 Go
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about it is to sort the segments and then collapse the ones that have the same value and are back to back.

```
require(data.table)

## generating a (similar ?) data set
df <- data.frame(dates = rep(as.Date('01-01-2010','%m-%d-%Y'),20) + sample(1:100,20), 
             sig = sample(c('stop', 'go'), replace = T, ))
             
df$sig <- as.character(df$sig)                 
             
df <- df[order(df$dates),]

### creating the lag variable for date 
df$dates2 <- c(NA,df$dates[1:nrow(df)-1])


### creating the lag variable for sig

df$sig2 <- c(NA,df$sig[1:nrow(df)-1])

## creating a variable that triggers a new segment 
df$grp <- as.numeric(df$sig != df$sig2)
df$grp[1] <- 0

### the cumsum of the trigger is actually the grouping variable 

df$grp2 <- cumsum(df$grp)


## using data table 
 dt <- data.table(df)


 dt2 <- dt[,.(start = min(dates), end = max(dates), sig = sig ), 
       grp]
```

## the results

```
 grp      start        end  sig
 1:   0 2010-01-05 2010-04-11   go
 2:   0 2010-01-05 2010-04-11   go
 3:   0 2010-01-05 2010-04-11   go
 4:   0 2010-01-05 2010-04-11 stop
 5:   0 2010-01-05 2010-04-11 stop
 6:   0 2010-01-05 2010-04-11   go
 7:   0 2010-01-05 2010-04-11 stop
 8:   0 2010-01-05 2010-04-11   go
```

Comment: If you're using `data.table`, then `rleid` might be helpful - `signal[, rleid(Sig)]` for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the expected result. It is difficult to judge because you have made up your own data instead of using the sample data provided by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This old question hasn't got a proper answer so far. Here is a concise `data.table` solution using the `rleid()` function:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(signal)[order(Date), .(Start = first(Date)), by = .(rleid(Sig), Sig)][
  , Stop := shift(Start, type = "lead")][
    -.N, !"rleid"]
```

> ```
>     Sig      Start       Stop
> 1:   Go 2012-03-25 2012-04-15
> 2: Stop 2012-04-15 2012-06-24
> 3:   Go 2012-06-24 2012-10-14
> 4: Stop 2012-10-14 2012-12-02
> 5:   Go 2012-12-02 2012-12-16
> ```

#### Explanation

`setDT()`coerces `signal` to class `data.table`. Then `signal` is ordered by `Date` and aggregated by continuous streaks of `Sig` using `rleid()` and by the value of `Sig`. The first row of each group is picked. To determine the stop dates the new `Start` column is shifted forward. Finally, the last row and the `rleid` grouping variable are removed.

#### Data

OP's data:

```
library(data.table)
signal <- fread(
  " i          Date Sig
1  2012-03-25  Go
2  2012-04-15 Stop
3  2012-04-22 Stop
4  2012-05-13 Stop
5  2012-05-20 Stop
6  2012-06-24  Go
7  2012-09-23  Go
8  2012-09-30  Go
9  2012-10-14 Stop
10 2012-12-02  Go
11 2012-12-16 Stop", drop = 1L, data.table = FALSE
)
```